# Eclipse Java Editor does not show minus sign(-)

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse version is: 3.4.1

Whenever I type minus sign(-) in the java editor, I am not seeing hyphen(-) and in place of this I am seeing another symbol. It shows as (' to the bottom). If I copy and paste in a notepad, it shows as (-).

Please let me know if anyone has seen this.

Thanks,
Mango

Comment: By `(' to the bottom`, do you mean `,` (a comma)?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a font problem.  To confirm, save the editor contents to a file, and open it in your favorite editor.